# .htaccess redirect homepage only

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to 301 redirect homepage

```
https://example.com/
```

to

```
https://example.com/category/news
```

But I have a newsletter that uses this URL after submit:

```
https://example.com.pl/?na=s
```

So after basic 301 redirection, newsletter submit link also redirects to `https://example.com/category/news`

How to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are currently issuing the redirect, but in order to target the query string (in order to exclude that particular query string) then you'll need to use mod_rewrite.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=na=s
RewriteRule ^$ /category/news [QSD,R=301,L]
```

The above redirects the homepage (ie. an empty URL-path), but specifically excludes the URL with the exact query string `na=s`.

The `QSD` flag discards any other query string that might have been on the initial request.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing (since the erroneous 301 *permanent* redirect will have been cached by the browser). Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid caching issues.

---

> So after basic 301 redirection, newsletter submit link also redirects to `https://example.com/category/news`

Although, ordinarily you would expect it to have redirected to `https://example.com/category/news?na=s`, unless you had taken explicit measures to remove the query string from the redirect response.